# apt-pkg compile issue

Tags: compilation, include, compiler-errors, apt

I am trying to compile a third party code which uses apt-pkg. The error is

```
/usr/include/apt-pkg/depcache.h:188: error: ‘regex_t’ was not declared in this scope
```

I've verified that regex.h exists at /usr/include/regex.h

I am using ubuntu 10.4 64 bit to compile code.

what could be wrong?

Comment: Telling us what you are trying to compile might be helpful

Comment: Oval Interpreter http://sourceforge.net/projects/ovaldi/files/ovaldi/5.10%20Build%201/

Answer (score 0):

You need to include regex.h in depcache.h before you use regex_t, or include it in whatever code includes depcache.h, before you include depcache.h.

Or perhaps there is an #ifdef that is set incorrectly for your environment and that is blocking the include of regex.h.